# How to retrieve the selectd month in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I need to retrieve the currently selected month in wordpress but I dunno what function to use.

The scenario is:

- I click on one of the months in the list (say August)
- I get redirected to the page containing all the posts published in August

In this page I need to print the name of the month: something like "You are browsing the articles published in **August 2014**".

How do I do that?

Cheers

Comment: It would be the archive title (month/year). What have you tried?

Comment: archive.php should get you there. [Have a look at the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_an_Archive_Index)

Comment: yes archive is the page where I get to. But what if I want to print the name of the month on the page?

Comment: <?= single_month_title(); ?> See http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/29339/how-can-i-get-the-month-name-from-archive, this Q seems to be a duplicate albeit on wordpress.stackexchange.

Comment: @dwhite.me: cool! put it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<?= single_month_title(); ?>`

See the [WP Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/single_month_title) for use, but just popping it in wherever needed should suffice.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how the bundled theme twenty fourteen achieves this in archive.php. This will shows the date for yearly, monthly and daily archives

```
<header class="page-header">

<h1 class="page-title">
    <?php
        if ( is_day() ) :
            printf( __( 'Daily Archives: %s', 'twentyfourteen' ), get_the_date() );

        elseif ( is_month() ) :
            printf( __( 'Monthly Archives: %s', 'twentyfourteen' ), get_the_date( _x( 'F Y', 'monthly archives date format', 'twentyfourteen' ) ) );

        elseif ( is_year() ) :
            printf( __( 'Yearly Archives: %s', 'twentyfourteen' ), get_the_date( _x( 'Y', 'yearly archives date format', 'twentyfourteen' ) ) );

        else :
            _e( 'Archives', 'twentyfourteen' );

        endif;
    ?>
</h1>
</header><!-- .page-header -->
```